# IndexError: index 35 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 10

Tags: python, numpy

**Problem**
I am working on a neural network in Python and had this error come up. Now I don't see any problems since it worked before with a different dataset. Now I get the following error:

...
File "e:\PWS Bart\initiate model.py", line 550, in forward
correct_confidences = y_pred_clipped[range(samples), y_true]
IndexError: index 35 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 10

*The code on line 550 is:*

```
    # Forward pass
    def forward(self, y_pred, y_true):

        # Number of samples in a batch
        samples = len(y_pred)

        # Clip data to prevent division by 0
        # Clip both sides to not drag mean towards any value
        y_pred_clipped = np.clip(y_pred, 1e-7, 1 - 1e-7)

        # Probabilities for target values -
        # only if categorical labels
        if len(y_true.shape) == 1:
            correct_confidences = y_pred_clipped[
                range(samples),
                y_true
            ]

        # Mask values - only for one-hot encoded labels
        elif len(y_true.shape) == 2:
            correct_confidences = np.sum(
                y_pred_clipped * y_true,
                axis=1
            )

        # Losses
        negative_log_likelihoods = -np.log(correct_confidences)
        return negative_log_likelihoods
```

*Edit:* The code on line 550 is the one that defines correct_confidences

*The value of y_pred:*

```
    [[0.09999657 0.10003116 0.09997115 ... 0.09980713 0.09992861 0.09994321]
     [0.10006691 0.10000683 0.10005932 ... 0.0998411  0.09988077 0.09978568]
     [0.09997768 0.10003725 0.09997757 ... 0.09985325 0.10000801 0.09984406]
     ...
     [0.09993309 0.10008678 0.10013765 ... 0.09980296 0.09991061 0.09999865]
     [0.09991049 0.09992879 0.09992588 ... 0.09985736 0.10001095 0.0999448 ]
     [0.10004579 0.10000289 0.10012186 ... 0.09978612 0.09996389 0.09980298]]
```

*The value of y_true:*

```
[35  5 15 23  6 25 33  8 27  0  8 17 45 43 33  8 43 39 21 28 20 31 30  1
 45  9  3 36 35 44 30 30  6 32 12 41 46 11  7 41 29 46 23 46 20 12 31 31
 22 46  5 33  2 20  8  0  0 17  0  4 20 43 45 14 17 45 20 46 18  6  8 32
 41 27  4 28  8 33  8 22 32 10 23 15 43 46 43 45 23 37 30 10 21  6 42  4
  0 43 36 43  8 41 37 38  2  0 32 40  1 39  1 18  0 15 29 33  6  0 18 40
 45 32 23  2 44 32 10 14]
```

*The value of samples:*
128

*The value of y_true.shape:*
(128,)

**Question:**
Is there someone here that knows how I would go about solving this?

Comment: Why do you use 35 as index for an axis of size 10?

Comment: @mkrieger1 the problem is that I never use an index of 35. And this all worked with a different dataset.

Comment: **You *do* use an index of 35, since 35 is the first value in `ytrue`** (you posted `ytrue = [35  5 15 23  6 ...]`). In your code, you try to index `y_pred_clipped` using `ytrue`, so for each value `i` in `ytrue`, numpy tries to retrieve the value at index `i` from axis 1 in `y_pred_clipped`.

Comment: @PeterY. ooh yea I see. I still wonder why this error occurs now when I had no problems with a different dataset?

Comment: What is the difference between the datasets?

Comment: @mkrieger1 one has labels of 0 to 10 and the new one has labels 0 to 46.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I may have found the problem. The model was set in stone 128 by 10. So I made it 128 by 46 which should fix it. So the problem was no where in the mentioned lines. It was way earlier.

Comment: @mkrieger1 it is working now!